# Is there anything similar to Oracle Analytics in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I used Oracle Analytics for SQL. Is something like that available in SQL Server 2008 Express and Compact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Server has Analysis Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/analysis-services.aspx), but this isn't available in the free versions: Express and Compact.

see:
[SQL Server 2008: Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx)

[Compare SQL Server 2008 Edition Features](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx)

SQL Server does have these: **[Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)** and **[Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)** which may bee what your are after.